# ios [NSURL URLWithString:requestUrl relativeToURL:baseUrl]. if requestUrl contains string '/User/Page' ， return nil

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

```
[NSURL URLWithString:requestUrl relativeToURL:baseUrl]
```

if requestUrl contains '/User/page', return nil.

[image: image:]

If you want a test.

```
NSString *reqUrl1 = @"/api/v3.1/User​/Page/";

NSString *reqUrl2 = @"api/v3.1/User​/Page";

NSString *reqUrl3 = @"/api/v3.1/User​/Page/";

NSString *reqUrl4 = @"/api/v3.1/Follow/Page";

NSString *reqUrl5 = @"/api/v3.1/User/Follow";

NSString *reqUrl6 = @"/api/v3.1/User/Pollow";

NSString *reqUrl7 = @"api/v3.2/User​/Page";

NSString *reqUrl8 = @"api/v3.2/User​/Page/aaa/bbb";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://appgateway.xxx.xx-xxx.xxx.com/"];

NSString *lastUrl1 = [NSURL URLWithString:reqUrl1 relativeToURL:url].absoluteString;

NSString *lastUrl2 = [NSURL URLWithString:reqUrl2 relativeToURL:url].absoluteString;

NSString *lastUrl3 = [NSURL URLWithString:reqUrl3 relativeToURL:url].absoluteString;

NSString *lastUrl4 = [NSURL URLWithString:reqUrl4 relativeToURL:url].absoluteString;

NSString *lastUrl5 = [NSURL URLWithString:reqUrl5 relativeToURL:url].absoluteString;

NSString *lastUrl6 = [NSURL URLWithString:reqUrl6 relativeToURL:url].absoluteString;

NSString *lastUrl7 = [NSURL URLWithString:reqUrl7 relativeToURL:url].absoluteString;

NSString *lastUrl8 = [NSURL URLWithString:reqUrl8 relativeToURL:url].absoluteString;

NSLog(@"============");

// ------------------------------------------------------

(lldb) po lastUrl1

 nil

(lldb) po lastUrl2

 nil

(lldb) po lastUrl3

 nil

(lldb) po lastUrl4

http://appgateway.xxx.xx-xxx.xxx.com/api/v3.1/Follow/Page

(lldb) po lastUrl5

http://appgateway.xxx.xx-xxx.xxx.com/api/v3.1/User/Follow

(lldb) po lastUrl6

http://appgateway.xxx.xx-xxx.xxx.com/api/v3.1/User/Pollow

(lldb) po lastUrl7

 nil

(lldb) po lastUrl8

 nil
```

Comment: `NSURL *hardCoded = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/api/v3.1/Follow/Page" relativeToURL:baseURL];` works. I coded this: https://pastebin.com/mx7J4njm which is easier to read/modify. Problem is elsewhere: Start with "/", end with no "/" which doesn't seems to be a case you have for "User/Page"...

Answer (score 0):

@Larme . Sorry, there is something wrong with my example. The third example is modified to "/api/v3.1/user/page". That's not true.

Follow your code. Print as

Error: http://appgateway.xxx.xx-xxx.xxx.com/ + /api/v3.1/user/page
Success: http://appgateway.xxx.xx-xxx.xxx.com/api/v3.1/follow/page

But I found a problem by looping through the characters.

```
for (NSString *aRequestURL in requestURLs) {
        for(int i=0; i<aRequestURL.length; i++){
            unichar ch = [aRequestURL characterAtIndex: i];
            printf("%hu", ch);
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", aRequestURL);
}
```

There is a strange character '8203' between '/user' and '/page'. Thank you very much for the code. It broadened my thinking

But I don't know why '8203' affects URL generation